# Vanishing locus generic section $(\mathrm{sym}^2 \mathcal{R})(1)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, projective-geometry, schubert-calculus

Let $n = 2m$ be an even integer and let $\mathcal{R}$ the tautological bundle on the Grassmannian $\mathrm{Gr}(2,n)$. I am looking for an explicit description of the degener
The bundle $(\mathrm{Sym}^2 \mathcal{R})(1)$ having some (weak) positivity property, one may expect that the codimension of the vanishig locus is $3$, but I am not able to describe it explicitely (in termes of Schubert cycles for instance).

**EDITS**
Owing to the comments, I realize there is a mistake in the twist and that my question is completely ill-formulated (with respect to what I am looking for). I am sorry for that, I will edit the question when I find out what is the correct formulation.

Comment: Do you mean tautological or dual tautological? If $R$ is tautological then $(S^2R)(1)$ has no global sections...

Comment: (Assuming that $R$ is the quotient bundle): what do you mean by describe explicitely? If you just want the cohomology class, that's an easy computation. But you won't get more than that.

Comment: If $\mathcal{R}$ is the rank 2 bundle, then $\mathrm{Sym}^2\mathcal{R}(1)$ is rank 3. So, provided that it has sections (by correct choices as remarked by others), the generic section has vanishing locus described  by the 3-rd Chern class of this bundle. Given the usual formulas, (say in Fulton's book), the description in terms of Schubert cycles (upto rational equivalence) should be possible. Is this the kind of answer you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

(I am assuming here that with $R$ you mean the dual of the tautological (otherwise, as Sasha remarked, the bundle $(Sym^2 R)(1)$ has no sections)).

I don't know exactly what kind of informations you are after, but some (possibly interesting) facts:

1. $c_1((Sym^2 R)(1)=6H$. In particular the zero locus $Z(\sigma) \subset Gr(2,n)$ of a general global section will be (a codimension three) smooth general type for $n<6$, Calabi-Yau for $n=6$ and Fano afterwards.
2. For $n=4$ you get a curve of genus 21.
3. For $n=6$ you get a CY 5-fold with
   $h^{1,1}=1, \ h^{2,2}=2, \ h^{4,1}=174, \ h^{3,2}=1905$,
   and all the others non-obvious Hodge numbers equal 0.
4. For $n>6$ you get Fano varieties with quite a large cohomology in the central level (but not particularly interesting numbers). They seem to have all $\rho=h^{1,1}=1$. I have done only a few checks (up to $n=10$), but one can probably prove this in general using a Barth-Lefschetz type theorem.